# Does JVM store memory in system ? If so, how to clear it?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, out-of-memory

I am running an application using NetBeans and in the project properties I have set the Max JVM heap space to 1 GiB.

But still, the application crashes with Out of Memory.

Does the JVM have memory stored in system? If so how to clear that memory?

Comment: Maybe your application haven't enough PermGen memory?

Comment: The reason for the crash is in your code. Analyze what your code does with memory allocation.

Comment: the code will run fine after a fresh check out.. After continuous build, run, debug for about 1 or 2 days the Out of Memory error starts.

Comment: @nigelthomas Do you mean the application has been running for 1-2 days before it crashes?

Comment: Is the OutOfMemoryError occurring for your application, or the IDE? If it does that it sounds like it may be the development environment throwing the exception, not your application. The JVM doesn't "hold on" to any memory after it exits.

Comment: The Out Of Memory occurs while running the application.

Comment: Nigel - as @berry120 pointed out - use a profiler. Almost certainly you have a memory leak. There are many articles on how to find a memory leak (i.e. you are somehow preventing old objects from being collected by the GC). An article specifically for Netbeans is: http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/nb-profiler-uncoveringleaks_pt1.html

Comment: There are 2 kinds of OutOfMemory that you can get.  One is related to max memory but the other is related to PermGen space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @camobap the reason for the OutOfMemory was because **Perm Gen** size was set very low. Now the issue is resolved.

Thank you all for the answers and comments.

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to analyse your code with a profiler - Netbeans has a good one. This will show you where the memory is tied up in your application, and should give you an idea as to where the problem lies.

The JVM will garbage collect objects as much as it can before it runs out of memory, so chances are you're holding onto references long after you no longer need them. Either that, or your application is genuinely one that requires a lot of memory - but I'd say it's far more likely to be a bug in your code, especially if the issue only crops up after running the application for a long period of time.

Answer (score 4):

I do not fully understand all details of your question, but I guess the important part is understandable.

The `OutOfMemoryError` (not an exception) is thrown if the memory allocated to your JVM does not suffice for the objects created in your program. In your case it might help to increase the available heap space to more than 1 GByte. If you think 1 GByte is enough, you may have a memory leak (which, in Java, most likely means that you have references to objects that you do not need anymore - maybe in some sort of cache?).

Answer (score 3):

Java reserves virtual memory for its maximum heap size on startup.  As the program uses this memory, more main memory is allocated to it by the OS.  Under UNIX this appear as resident memory.  While Java programs can swap to disk, the Garbage Collection performs extremely badly if part of the heap is swapped and it can result in the whole machine locking up or having to reboot.  If your program is not doing this, you can be sure it is entirely in main memory.

Depending on what your application does it might need 1 GB, 10 GB or 100 GB or more.  If you cannot increase the maximum memory size, you can use a memory profiler to help you find ways to reduce consumption.  Start with VisualVM as it is built in and free and does a decent job.  If this is not enough, try a commercial profiler such as YourKit for which you can get a free evaluation license (usually works long enough to fix your problem ;)

The garbage collector automatically cleans out the memory as required and may be doing this every few seconds, or even more than once per second.  If it is this could be slowing down your application, so you should consider increasing the maximum size or reducing consumption.

Comment: The application closes by itself while the debugging the IDE (Netbeans) will be continuing. Is this because of Out Of Memory ?

Comment: The thread which throws the OutOfMemoryError can die if you don't catch it.  This can cause the program to exit if it's the only non-daemon thread.  You can have the debugger trap this error to determine exactly where it is occurring, however it is usually not a simple bug so the debugger isn't so useful for diagnosing this sort of problem.  The problem is usually that you are using too much memory for the amount you have allowed the program to use. You have to analyse the whole memory usage to determine why that is.

Comment: @AndrewAlcock 1) The virtual memory size of a JVM includes the maximum heap size on startup. It does this to ensure that the heap is continuous in terms of address space. The minimum size is the point which it will grow up to freely.  A hello world program will not use the minimum size and the JVM may still GC before the minimum size is reached. 2) This is true, but JVM behaves so badly if even a small portion is swapped that you can assume after a GC it won't be swapped.

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler doesn't allocate 1 GiB as I think you are thinking. Java dynamically allocates the needed memory and garbage collects it too, every time it allocates memory it checks whether it has enough space to do so, and if not crashes. I am guessing somewhere in your code, because it would be near impossible to write code that allocates that many variables, you have an array or ArrayList that takes up all the memory. In the case of an array you probably has a variable allocating the size of it and you did some calculation to it that made it take too much memory. In the case of an ArrayList I believe you might have a loop that goes too many iterations adding elements to it.

Check your code for the above errors and you should be good.